# Conditional value assignment to multiple columns based on some other column value

Tags: arrays, r, loops, if-statement

I have been stuck with this problem and I am sure for some of you this will not be too hard to solve. I've had no success in finding the answer in this forum.

The company I work at has a rotational program in which employees spend some time in multiple divisions and, at the end of some period, they get evaluated for a more senior division (promotion). Most will finish their program in 3 years, then a few more in the 4th and 5th. A small percentage (around 15%) does not complete the program. The dataset is fairly large and goes back more than 30 years. Some data is entered manually and is prone to data entry mistakes. The columns `cont1`, `cont2`,...,`cont7` flags whether the individual is still in the rotational program. The columns `prom3`, `prom4` and `prom5` has a `'Y'` if the employee has successfully completed the program in 3, 4 and 5 years respectively. So a `'Y'` in `prom3` means that there will also be an `'Y'` in `prom4` and `prom5`, and consequently a `NA` in `cont3`,...,`cont7` because the person is no longer in the rotational program. If an individual is not promoted in year 3 but, instead, do it in year 4, then `prom4` is `'Y'` and `cont4`,...,`cont7` is `NA`. By now you see the problem. The issue is that I have more years. I understand I can use `ifelse()` but the code gets quite messy and long. I would like to find a solution to do this in a more elegant way, dynamically.

I need to find a way to dynamically program if `prom3` has a `'Y'` then `cont2` is `'Y'` and `cont3`,...,`cont7` is `NA`. If `id` has `'Y'` in `prom4` then `cont4`,...,`cont7` is `NA` and `cont2` and `cont3` is `'Y'` and so on. Something like:

```
contYears <- seq(2,7, by=1)

promYears <- seq(3,5, by=1)

if (paste0("prom",promYears)=='Y'){
is.na(paste0("cont",contYears)) while contYears >= promYears)}
else paste0("cont",contYears)=='Y'
```

Sorry for the not so elegant try above!

Thank you for your help!!! Below a toy df:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble::data_frame(id = seq(1,100, by=1),
                     cont2 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.9, 0.1)),
                     cont3 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)),
                     cont4 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.5, 0.5)),
                     cont5 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.25,0.75)),
                     cont6 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.15,0.85)),
                     cont7 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.10,0.9)),
                     prom3 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.5,0.5)),
                     prom4 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.75,0.25)),
                     prom5 = sample(c('Y', NA), 100, replace=T, prob = c(0.85,0.15)))

head(df) 

id cont2 cont3 cont4 cont5 cont6 cont7 prom3 prom4 prom5
1     Y     Y     Y  <NA>     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
2     Y     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y     Y
3     Y     Y     Y  <NA>     Y  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
4     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
5     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
6  <NA>     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Here is how the output should look like:

```
id cont2 cont3 cont4 cont5 cont6 cont7 prom3 prom4 prom5
1     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
2     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y     Y 
3     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
4     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
5     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
6     Y     Y     Y     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

So the `prom[:digit:]` triggers the `cont[:digit:]` columns to `'Y'` or `NA`. And if someone is promoted within 3 years, then of course the other promotion columns will be `'Y`'as well. As I said before, I can do this with `ifelse()` statements but I have more than 7 years for `cont[:digit:]` and 5 for `prom[:digit:]` which makes the code really awkward to read and time consuming.

Comment: Can you show your expected output based on the example?

Comment: Please edit your post and update it there

Comment: It seems that all the `cont` columns are irrelevant if you just fill them with data already contained in the `prom` columns.

Comment: I think your 'cont6' should be NA for id 3 in expected output

Comment: Hi akrun, yes. Just corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `apply`

```
df[grep("cont", names(df))] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, FUN= function(x) {
         i1 <- seq_len(6)>which.max(x[7:9]=="Y")
       if(length(i1)>0) replace(x[1:6], i1, NA) else rep("Y", 6)}))
head(df, 6)
#   id cont2 cont3 cont4 cont5 cont6 cont7 prom3 prom4 prom5
#1  1     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
#2  2     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y     Y
#3  3     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
#4  4     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y
#5  5     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     Y     Y
#6  6     Y     Y     Y     Y     Y     Y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```